# add new object to list unless an object with the same name property value already exists

Tags: reactjs

I would like to filter through array of objects and remove existing ones

```
const [objects, setObjects] = useState();
```

I call

```
setObjects([
  0: {id: "1", user_id: "1", name: "ben"},
  1: {id: "2", user_id: "1", name: "brad"},
  2: {id: "3", user_id: "2", name: "tom"},
])
```

then I want to add more objects.

though only add them if an object with the same name value does not exist already

so the below object won't get added as we already have someone with the name ben

```
const object = {id: "2", user_id: "1", name: "ben"}
```

so here I go objects.filter for name.value if contains object.name {
alert(already have this object with this name in the list so we will not add them!)
return
}

```
setObjects((prevState) => ([...prevState, object]));
```

So that I don't add another object with the same name?
And may there be an issue with `setObjects` and the getting objects so soon and if so how can I set them then get them asap?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add an object to an array if it doesn't have the same key with one of the objects in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435009/add-an-object-to-an-array-if-it-doesnt-have-the-same-key-with-one-of-the-object)

Comment: See also [Check if object value exists within a Javascript array of objects and if not add a new object to array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22844560/215552) if the lodash-iness of that question irks you.

Answer (score 1):

You can first check to see if there is an object with the same `name` property value. If the answer is yes then do nothing (or alert something like you did), if the answer is no add the new object to the list.

```
const addNewObj = (newObj) => {
   if(objects.find(({name}) => name === newObj.name)) {
     alert('')
     return;
    }

   setObjects((prevState) => [...prevState, newObj]);
}
```